# Conditional event binding - vuejs

Tags: events, vue.js

In my scenario I have mouseover and mouseout events that I want to bind to conditionally (e.g only if user is on a device that has a mouse).

I realize I can have the condition in the event handler itself but that would still be allocating the memory for the event handlers which is unnecessary.

Is there a way to make the **event binding itself** conditional?

(to be clear, what I'd like is to be able to short-circuit the event subscription so the underlying addEventListener operation never happens if the condition is false)

Comment: You could use `v-if hasMouse` and have one branch with the events and the other without. Probably use [scoped slots](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots) to insert the common code.

Comment: That's OK for very simple components but if your template is substantial (I'm working with a complex SVG in this case) it becomes a pain

Comment: The computed property looks to be a great answer. Is there a reason you don't want to type it up and mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: Could not get any of these solutions working reliably when using event modifiers (e.g. `.stop`)

Comment: @user9645 you are correct! Had the same issue. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70814750/2698019) for implementing `.stop`.

Answer (score 134):

### Update (February 2021)

Several solutions seem to be accepted on [Github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7349), whereas my original answer is not.  I'm rounding them up here for convenience:

**Solution 1a** (see [Engin Yapici's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57331234/5405967) below):

```
v-on="enableClick ? { click: clickHandler } : {}"
```

**Solution 1b** (see [Heals Legodi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65212994/5405967) below):

```
v-on="enableClick ? { click: () => clickHandler(params) } : {}"
```

**Solution 2a** (see [rvy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65966771/5405967) below and this [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pbastowski/v0wt5qpo/63/))

```
@[eventName]="clickHandler"
```

**Solution 2b** (from [coyotte508's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042274/conditional-event-binding-vuejs#comment121616107_65966771); 2a without the computed property):

```
@[isClickable&&`click`]="clickHandler"
```

**Solution 3** (mentioned [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7349#issuecomment-619305998); seems to be compatible with event modifiers):

```
@click="enableClick && clickHandler"
```

### Original answer

> This works as of Vue 2.6:
>
> ```
> <div
>   @mouseover="enableMouseover ? mouseoverHandler : null"
>   @click="enableClick ? clickHandler : null"
>   ...
> >
> ```
>
> > While an event resolves to `null`, the binding will be removed.
>
> https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7349#issuecomment-458405684

### Comments on original answer

It seems to be something I came up with accidentally by misunderstanding that Github thread. But I know from my own testing that it definitely worked back when I posted it. And people continued to upvote it right up to when I made this edit, implying the solution still had some merit.  So give it a try if you like.

But after a downvote and a couple of negative comments, I felt the need to improve my answer to save future readers potential headaches.  Note that pretty much all the answers to this question refer to the same Github thread, so if you've got time, you might want to go right to the source to learn more.  There are many options discussed there, and I suspect more will continue to be posted over time.

Comment: Binding `@click` to `null`, now returns a warning from Vue: `[Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "click": got null`.

Comment: The syntax in this example doesn't seem to work. Not sure why it's so upvoted.
Other answers are good. You need to use `v-on="condition ? { click: handler } : {}"`
or actual dynamic name of event that resolves to null (but it probably need to be a [computed field](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7349#issuecomment-621699548))

Comment: This is wrong. The linked issue on github shows the proper solution.

Comment: I added a comment on @rve's answer - maybe you can add it as well? It's a version without needing to create a `computed` for the event name

Comment: “compatible with event modifiers” is not really true. Maybe it is for some, but not for `.stop`. For modifiers that don't work, just implement them yourself like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70814750/2698019).

Comment: None of these work when `enableClick` is part of props passed to the slot by a child component. In that case ```:[enableClick?`onClick`:``]="handler"``` can be used. It has the benefits of 2a/2b that the component does not think it has a handler (so for example it would not display the click cursor instead of arrow) unlike 1 and 3, but nor 2a nor 2b works with slot props. Note how the `click` event became `onClick` with this syntax. See more details down in my answer.

Answer (score 30):

Following [this discussion](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7349) it appears the best way to achieve this is to bind v-on to a specification object containing the events you are interested in subscribing to and place your conditionals there like so:

`<div v-on="{ mouseover: condition ? handler : null, click: ... }">`

Some notes:

- Passing *null* for a handler means the underlying `addEventLisetener`
  will **not** happen - which is what we want
- This means grouping all the event subscriptions into one v-on
  attribute rather then splitting it into separate and explicit
  bindings (`<div @mouseover='...' @click='...'/>`)
- If this is a long living component and the underlying data    changes
  frequently (leading to rebinding) you should be paying    attention
  to the disposal of the subscriptions (i.e the corresponding `removeEventListener`) as subscriptions made in    one bind pass
  will not be disposed of on subsequent ones. Evaluate as per    your
  use case...

Comment: The new way to do conditional event binding: `v-on="condition ? { mouseover: handler } : {}"` [from the convesation linked in the answer](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7349#issuecomment-380431978)

Answer (score 25):

This is what I'm using:

`v-on="condition ? { click: handler } : {}"` ([Reference](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7349#issuecomment-380431978))

I get `Invalid handler for event "click": got null` with `v-on="{ click: condition ? handler : null }"`

Comment: I am trying this on a text-field but it isn't working for me yet it has worked for me before on a card. This time the event isn't added at all

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me on an anchor tag, on Vue 2.6.11.

Answer (score 9):

If you get the 'Invalid handler for event "click": got null' error and your handler function expects some parameters then you should wrap your handler in a function.

So this >

```
v-on="condition ? { blur: () => handler(params) } : {}"
```

Instead of

```
v-on="condition ? { click: handler(params) } : {}"
```

Comment: This worked for me in Vue 2.

Comment: That's the best solution :)

Answer (score 5):

Even more simpler would be to use render functions for that. You won't need to be manually removing the listeners and taking care of them. Also uses simple JS syntax with no mixins.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    counter: 0
  }),
  methods: {
    handleClick() {
      this.counter++;
    }
  },
  render(h) {
    return h(
      "div",
      IS_MOBILE_DEVICE
        ? {}
        : {
            on: { click: this.handleClick }
          },
      this.counter
    );
  }
});
```

Full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nw6vyo6knj

Comment: Render functions would work well for a very simple component but in some cases (I'm working with a complex SVG) are unmanageable

Answer (score 5):

I am unable to comment on answers so I am adding my own.

**Solution 3** from the approved answer does not work - parentheses are missing.
The correct syntax in this case would be:

```
@click="enableClick && clickHandler()"
```

Here is [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-kalam-3u4bif?file=/src/App.vue)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do something like that you could just apply the event listener manually by adding a `ref` on the `element` you want to apply the event to, then using that to bind the event listener in the `mounted` hook if the condition is met:

**Markup**

```
<button ref="button">
  Mouse Over Me
</button>
```

**Vue Instance**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    let hasMouse = true;

    // If the user has a mouse, add the event listeners
    if (hasMouse) {
      let button = this.$refs.button

      button.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
        this.mouseover = true
      })

      button.addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
        this.mouseover = false
      })
    }

  },
  data: {
    mouseover: false
  }
})
```

Here's a JSFiddle for that: https://jsfiddle.net/0fderek6/

If you don't like that approach, you could also use a `directive` and place the conditional in there, you could then place that in a `mixin` to make it reusable:

**Mixin**

```
const mouseEvents = {
  directives: {
    mouseEvents: {
      bind(el, binding, vnode) {
        let hasMouse = true;

        if (hasMouse) {
          el.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
            vnode.context.mouseover = true
          })

          el.addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
            vnode.context.mouseover = false
          })
        }
      }
    }
  },
  data: {
    mouseover: false
  }
}
```

**Vue Instance**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mixins: [mouseEvents]
})
```

**Markup**

```
<button v-mouse-events>
  Mouse Over Me
</button>
```

Here's the JSFiddle for that: https://jsfiddle.net/nq6x5qeq/

**EDIT**

If you like the `directive` approach, all you need to do is add an `unbind` hook to remove the listener, you can then have the `binding arg` be the event type and the `binding value` be the handler:

```
Vue.directive('mouse', {
  bind(el, binding) {
      if (hasMouse) {
        console.log(binding.arg + ' added')
          // bind the event listener to the element
        el.addEventListener(binding.arg, binding.value)
      }
    },
    unbind(el, binding) {
      if (hasMouse) {
        console.log(binding.arg + ' removed')
        el.removeEventListener(binding.arg, binding.value)
      }
    }
});
```

Now all you need to do is add each listener exactly like you would with `v-bind`:

```
<div v-mouse:mouseover="mouseOverFunction"></div>
```

Here's the JSFiddle to show you how that works: https://jsfiddle.net/59ym6hdb/

Comment: This has one downside: it doesn't do a full `removeEventListener` in the `beforeDestroy` lifecycle event. On a lot of un-mounts -> mounts may perform even poorer than moving the condition into the event itself, it will just keep adding event listeners without ever removing them!

Comment: @AndreiGlingeanu I think we've both overcomplicated this, you would have to `unbind` the listeners in the directive (which would mean sharing state across directive hooks) and render functions aren't really maintainable. I would actually go for the solution provided by @RoyJ which is much simpler.

Comment: True. But, sometimes you really have to _really_skip an event conditionally on the same node. That may happen when you have a lot of logic attached to a single DOM node (like a lot of mouse* listeners that implement a simple drag-n-drop and you just need to skip the click event, for example). Of course we can debate on that forever, I just gave a simpler and a more low-level alternative solution.

Comment: @AndreiGlingeanu Yes, I thought your answer was a good answer. I think between us we've managed to provide pretty much all the options available. Happy new year!

Comment: Happy new year!

Comment: As @AndreiGlingeanu  pointed out the lack of  `removeEventListener` is a significant issue with the directive approach. And using explicit refs to handle this might be manageable if you had to do this for a single element but what if you had many - in my scenario I'm dealing with a complex SVG where depending on some context data only some elements need to have the events attached - this would become spahetti.

Comment: @asi I've updated my answer to remove the listeners with the directive.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use a `.stop` modifier, then none of the listed solutions will work. But it is actually easy, just implement whatever the modifier does in the event handler itself.

In the template: `@click="clickHandler"` (yes, always attached!)

Then for your handler:

```
function clickHandler(event) {
  if (whateverCondition) {
    event.stopPropagation()
    …
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7349#issuecomment-354937350) by Evan You

```html
<div v-on="{ mouseover: condition ? handler : null }">
```

should work and be clean.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to conditionally bind multiple events so I managed by doing this:
`v-on="isEnabled ? {mouseenter:open, mouseleave:close, touchend:toggle} : null"`

Answer (score 2):

None of the above solutions work, when you want to make the handler dependent on a condition, that uses props passed to the slot by the child.

In that case the below syntax can be used:

```js
:[enableClick?`onClick`:``]="clickHandler"
```

where `enableClick` is a prop received from the children as described here:
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#scoped-slots
and `onClick` is the event name (`click`) prefixed with `on` in camelCase
e.g.:

```html
<MyComponent v-slot="{ enableClick }">
  <OtherComponent :[enableClick?`onClick`:``]="clickHandler" />
</MyComponent>
```

and inside MyComponent template:

```html
<div>
  <slot :enableClick="isClickEnabled"></slot>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Conditional event binding works as follows:

```html
<div @[event]="handler" />
```

While event resolves to null, the binding will be removed.

(directly from https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7349#issuecomment-458405684 )

**Example:**

```html
<template>
  ...
  <span @[mayclick]="onClick">...</span>
  ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  computed: {
    mayclick: function() {
      return this.isClickable ? "click" : null;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onClick: function (message) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This also works: `<span @[isClickable&&\`click\`]="onClick">...</span>`

Answer (score 0):

For me this solution is the best to understand and 100% compatible with any VUE JS version

```
<div v-on:click="click()">...</div>

methods : {
    click() {
        if (yourCondition)
            yourhandler();
    },
},
```

If yourCondition evaluates to false, then click() method behaves such as no operation (a.k.a. noop)